# Add html in jquery with differents contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**I have this little script for add differents parts of code to the body in website**

```
WincontentBody=jQuery("<div class='wd_"+idw+"'id='win_container'>OK</div>"); 

WincontentBody=jQuery("</div>");


jQuery(WincontentBody).fadeIn(3000).appendTo('body');
```

I try to add code from WincontentBody to body but it doesn't work, some kind of error i have in syntax, because never show div

I think this it's fine but I can't find the problem, the idea it's to add all contents from the variable WincontentBody to the body

Is it possible to do this? Because i can't make it to work

Thank´s in advanced

Comment: Please be a little more specific on what issue you are facing. Is there any bug in [console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)?

Comment: I have var WincontentBody, and in each case has different value, i only want add all values to body from appendTo, no more, thank´s

Comment: You got it wrong. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and wrote your question properly for you. Take a look at SO in Spanish.

`fadeIn` and `appendTo` are `jQuery` methods. `WincontentBody` contains a string. You should first create a new `jQuery` object with your html.

```
$(WincontentBody).appendTo('body').fadeIn(3000); //first append, then fade in
```

If the `fadeIn` doesn't seem to work, it's probably because you will have to hide the elements (with some css) before inserting them into the page. Otherwise you'll be trying to fade in something that's already visible.

And I don't know if your code is actually formatted like that or it just got wrapped here, but you can't have multiline strings, unless you end each line with `\`.

---

Now (after your edit), you are creating two jQuery objects. One with the `div` and the other with nothing valid.

```
WincontentBody=jQuery("<div class='wd_"+idw+"'id='win_container'>OK</div>");
//WincontentBody now has the div 

WincontentBody=jQuery("</div>");
//WincontentBody now has nothing. The </div> is not being appended to what was in WincontentBody before, you're assigning a new value to it

jQuery(WincontentBody).fadeIn(3000).appendTo('body');
//You're appending WincontentBody (which has nothing valid) to the body
//Also, WincontentBody is already a jQuery instance, no need to call jQuery() again
```

What you should do is to create your `WincontentBody` with the html code, as you had before, and then use `$(WincontentBody)...` or `jQuery(WincontentBody)...`. Or put the whole html code in a single jQuery element like:

```
var WincontentBody=jQuery("----all the html code at once----");
WincontentBody.appendTo("body").fadeIn(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  WincontentBody = "<div class='wd_asdfas'id='win_container'>OK This is fine.</div>";

  $('.displayHere').append(WincontentBody);
  $('.displayHere').fadeIn(3000);
});
```

```css
body { background: #eee } 
.displayHere { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="displayHere">
  Hello Buddy
  </div>
</body>
```

**Updated**

I had made few changes.

1. I add the div named displayHere. I don't think it is good idea to
   give the fade effect to body of the webpage.
2. In jquery I split the functions to two different functions. Firstly it will update the details and then it will fade in.

Comment: That answer lacks explanations.